# How to use conditional property in pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a group based on **gsm monthly** with the result having total sum amount from the column **loan amount** but where **loan amount** matches to column value for **default**=1.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df['gsm_monthly'], df["loan_amt"], df['default']], axis = 1)
df1.groupby(df1.columns.values[0], as_index = False)[df1.columns.values[1]][df1['default'] == 1].sum()
```

My way does not work

Comment: We don't have your data, we don't know your columns, so please expand *"My way does not work"* into at least showing a snippet of your input and output. Why specifically doesn't it work, and what is the intended result? (This is important to make this a reusable recourse for other SO users in future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get multiple columns DataFrame is `pd.concat` not necessary, use list:

```
df1 = df[['gsm_monthly', "loan_amt",'default']]
```

Then first filter and aggregate in second step:

```
df1[df1['default'] == 1].groupby(df1.columns[0], as_index = False)[df1.columns[1]].sum()
```

Thank you for comment by @Rick M:

> Unless there's a reason to keep it generic, you can also just use the column names instead of referencing

```
df1[df1['default'] == 1].groupby('gsm_monthly', as_index = False)["loan_amt"].sum()
```

Comment: Unless there's a reason to keep it generic, you can also just use the column names instead of referencing `df.columns[i]`, like `df1[df1['default'] == 1].groupby('gsm_monthly', as_index=False)['loan_amt'].sum()`